# Transformar javax.persistence.Query para ArrayList

Tags: java, sql, array, query

É possível transformar um `javax.persistence.Query` em `ArrayList`.

Preciso retornar um objeto do tipo `Query` mas não pode ter todos os valores do resultado.

Quero eliminar alguns resultados baseado em alguns testes, o código se encontra abaixo.
Tenho que retornar um objeto do tipo `Query` pelo motivo de ser  uma classe genérica e não posso modificar o SQL.

```
        ...
        Query consulta = entityManager.createQuery(builder.toString());
        Query queryRetornoQuery;
        Set<String> chaveParametros = parametros.keySet();

        if (chaveParametros != null) {
            for (String parametro : chaveParametros) {
                consulta.setParameter(parametro, parametros.get(parametro));
            }
        }

        RelatorioSituacaoEmpresasContratadasTO empresasContratadasTO = null;
        List<RelatorioSituacaoEmpresasContratadas> listaSituacoes =
                consulta.getResultList();
        for (RelatorioSituacaoEmpresasContratadas relatorioSituacaoEmpresasContratadas : listaSituacoes) {
            empresasContratadasTO =
                    ConversorEntidadeTransferObject
                            .converterRelatorioSituacaoEmpresasContratadas(relatorioSituacaoEmpresasContratadas);

            /* O contrato está inativo? */
            if (hoje.compareTo(empresasContratadasTO
                    .getDataInicioContratoEmpresa()) < 0
                    || hoje.compareTo(empresasContratadasTO
                            .getDataFimContratoEmpresa()) > 0) {
                empresasContratadasTO
                        .setStatusContatoEmpresa(Constantes.CODIGO_STATUS_CONTRATO_EMPRESA_INATIVO);
                empresasContratadasTO
                        .setDescricaoStatusContratoEmpresa(Constantes.DESCRICAO_STATUS_CONTRATO_EMPRESA_INATIVO);
            }

            listaSituacoesEmpresasContratadas.add(empresasContratadasTO);
        }
        // No lugar dessa lista abaixo quero retornar um objeto Query
        return listaSituacoesEmpresasContratadas;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que retornar um `javax.persistence.Query` não parece ser uma boa ideia, se é que eu entendi direito o seu caso. Nada impediria o chamador de invocar métodos como `setParameter`, `getResultList`, `setMaxResults` ou `executeUpdate` no `Query` retornado e bagunçar com a consulta ou no mínimo não ter o resultado desejado, pois na verdade a consulta já foi feita e os resultados já estão prontos, eles só precisam ser filtrados.

Neste caso, o código que você tem já trás como resultado um `ArrayList` com os resultados. Se o seu problema for permitir a aplicação de filtros arbitrários em cima dos resultados, eu faria algo assim (java 8):

```java
public class Filterable<E> {
    private final List<E> results;

    public Filterable(List<E> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public Filterable<E> keepIf(Predicate<? super E> predicate) {
        results.removeIf(predicate.negate());
        return this;
    }

    public Filterable<E> removeIf(Predicate<? super E> predicate) {
        results.removeIf(predicate);
        return this;
    }

    public List<E> getResult() {
        // Retorna uma cópia, para que modificações na lista retornada não baguncem os filtros e vice-versa.
        return new ArrayList<>(results);
    }
}
```

E no final do seu método (além de mudar o tipo de retorno de acordo), você coloca isso:

```java
return new Filterable<>(listaSituacoesEmpresasContratadas);
```

Se você estiver usando uma versão do java anterior ao 8, você também vai precisar criar uma interface análoga ao `Predicate` e criar um método privado para implementar o `removeIf` da lista.

Ou, se você preferir, é possível retornar a `ArrayList` do jeito que está e apenas chamar o `removeIf` sempre que você quiser filtrá-la.